# How can I upload and import an SSL certifcate to AWS IAM?

Tags: aws

I have three files:

```
8e59b867828d4bdb.crt
8e59b867828d4bdb.pem
gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt.
```

Actually right now my `sss` certificate expired (https://www.sociorich.com/).

How can I upload `ssl` certifcate to AWS IAM?

Answer (score 0):

simply check at AWS documentation, it's all there https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/import-ssl-certificate-to-iam/

Comment: While a link to the official documentation is useful (particularly if AWS changes how they do things), an Answer here should document the necessary steps, even if they "only" solve the problem "today" (meaning: until AWS changes).